# Forgery of video

Tags: privacy, australia

I am 79 years old and a resident of a four storey building in NSW, comprising of 26 units. The multi-millionaire Chairman of our building's Strata Committee, who lives in the fourth floor’s penthouse and owns another two units in the building, acts as if he personally owns the whole building and has publicly verbally assaulted me, calling me a stupid old man who is always complaining. He controls the building's illegally installed security cameras and some months ago compiled and tampered with the cameras’ downloads, within our building, purporting to falsely show me kicking in our building's rear security door and damaging the locking mechanism. He subsequently lodged a complaint with the police accusing me of Malicious Damage (a criminal offence) which, after investigation, was rejected by the police. However, he instructed our Strata Manager to publicly screen the tampered video, without my permission, at the recent AGM causing me, my daughter (who is the owner of our unit) and son in law great humiliation. Our repeated requests for the past months for a copy of the video which we want to have examined by a by a digital forensic examination company to clear my name have been rejected by the Strata Committee, what can I do?

Comment: Does "NSW" refer to New South Wales, Australia?  I added the [tag:australia] tag as a guess.

Comment: Are you seeking suggestions on what to do so that you could do it yourself instead of hiring a lawyer? Why do you think that your respectful age is relevant here?

Answer (score 3):

If you are accurately representing the facts, this is a clear case of defamation. Your attorney will point out that you could sue him / them, since he apparently accused you of a crime (the accusation to the police, it's the later public accusation that counts). You can subpoena the video, in connection with a lawsuit. There is no way to force them to turn it over *without* a court proceeding.